# Recompiling an legacy BASIC program with .BAS files for 64-bit machines

Tags: compilation, basic, legacy-code

I have an old program written in Microsoft compiled BASIC that consists of two .BAS files. The only executable I have is a 16-bit .exe file compiled with QuickBASIC 7.x, designed for old machines (80286,80386,80486 Intel based) operating Microsoft DOS version 3.3 or higher. I want to run this program on a newer machine, but it is not compatible with the 16-bit executable. Is there any way to recompile this program for newer machines (Windows or MacOS)?

Additional Context:

```
The program is written in Basic and consists of two .BAS files and a .MAK linker file.
The goal is to run this program on a newer machine, which is not compatible with 16-bit executables.
Is there any solution or workaround to recompile the program for newer machines?
If possible, please provide step-by-step instructions or suggestions on how to achieve this.
```

The only available executable is a 16-bit .exe file, but it is not compatible with newer machines.

Comment: Search the web for vDos.  I use it to compile and test (run) legacy 16-bit code.  Your only other alternative is to get a 32-bit version of Windows.

Comment: Please clarify: You know the program consist of 2 bas files - do you have them? Or is "the only executable" the way you tell us, you have "only the executable"?

Comment: I have the two source code files +linker

Comment: If you have the sources (in ASCII format) you might try to compile IT with QB64 (is a free implementation of QB with an high compatibility with QB and a lot of intersting command) https://qb64.com/

Comment: Hi, https://www.freebasic.net/ it's a basic compiler with Quickbasic compatibility for Windows/Linux. You can call FBC.exe program.bas -Lang qb to enabled compatibility with QB or fblite if you need modern features into your program.